# How Drop the only subpartition of a partition

Tags: sql, database, database-partitioning, sql-drop, subpartition

While I am deleting subpartitions, one of the partition contains only one subpartition I got an error.

Error: **ORA-14629 cannot drop the only subpartition of a partition**

Can anyone know how to drop single subpartition of a partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the partition contains only one subpartition, you can drop the partition instead.

R

Comment: New subpartitions will be added to the partition, so old subpartitions have to be deleted

Comment: If this is an issue of replacing all the subpartitions, you can use this algorithm:

1. add a temporary subpartition X,

2. remove all the old subpartitions,

3. add the new subpartitions,

4. remove the temporary subpartition X.